# Identifying the x,y coordinates of dots in a manhattan plot

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, scatter-plot

I would like to identify the `x` and `y` positions of specific dots in my manhattan plot.

```
library(qqman)
manhattan(gwasResults)
```

With `head(gwasResults)` you will get:

```
  SNP CHR BP         P
1 rs1   1  1 0.9148060
2 rs2   1  2 0.9370754
3 rs3   1  3 0.2861395
4 rs4   1  4 0.8304476
5 rs5   1  5 0.6417455
6 rs6   1  6 0.5190959
```

I want to know the `x` and `y` coordinates in my plot, which corresponds to the dot at row == `6` in `gwasResults`.

Any idea how to extract this inf as one object?

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the point(s) on the plot use `highlight` with SNP value(s). For example:

```
manhattan(gwasResults, highlight = "rs6")
```

You can see the green dot in the picture (chr 1, left).

The y coordinate of the 6th row is

```
-log10(gwasResults[6, "P"])
```

(= 0.2847524)

The x coordinate depends on the CHR and BP defines the position inside the chromosome.

[image]